Server not accessible from different networks
A few days ago we moved several domains to a more powerful server hosted by one of the largest German hosters.
Since the move, we have 20% less traffic. Some customers report that they receive an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT message in Chrome when they try to access the online store.
Now I have the same problem when I try to access our websites via my home network.
I wanted to check the Apache2 logs to see if there is anything helpful there, but I can't access the server via SSH either.
If I switch to mobile data, I can use the websites and SSH as usual.
I couldn't find anything problem-related in the logs.
Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?
Short version:

20% of customers cannot access the website
SSH is also not possible, ping and DNS resolution work fine
No logs that are helpful


First guess is that your domain name has a long TTL, which means that different DNS servers around the world have your old IP address in cache.
For example, if TTL for your domain is one day (86400 seconds), it takes up to one day until DNS resolvers resolve your domain's IP address to the new location.

We had reduced the TTL to 1 hour in advance.
The move was also a week ago.
The problems also occur when we connect directly to the IP address via SSH
